# Why is Html.DisplayTextFor ignoring DisplayFormatAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I've read elsewhere that DisplayFormat just uses the DataFormatString in the same way string.Format does. I am trying to display a long as a phone number; in a console app, the following works:

```
const string PhoneFormat = "{0:###-###-####}";
long? phone = 8005551212;
string s = string.Format(PhoneFormat, phone);
```

s = "800-555-1212"

Why is it that when I use it in my view as

```
@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.Patient.Phone)
```

what is displayed is 8005551212

Here's the model...

```
public class Patient
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:###-###-####}")]
    public long? Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Also tried DisplayFor, which also does not work.

The only way that seems to work for me is

```
Html.Raw(string.Format("{0:###-###-####}", Model.Patient.Phone))
```

Comment: I don't see where yhou're using DisplayFormat, or any kind of format string in the code you posted.

Comment: My bad, I assumed it would have been obvious. The Phone property of my Patient object is decorated with the DisplayFormat attribute.

Comment: No, it's not obvious.  When you're having a problem, you need to show everything you're doing, because you might be making an error there.  So show your model with the attributes.

Answer (score 12):

I had a quick look into the [MVC3 source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781). I'm assuming you're specifying your format via DataAnnotations

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:###-###-####}")]
public long Phone { get; set; }
```

It looks like this is not applied when you use the `@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Property)` helper which apparently ends up doing a simple `ToString`. It is however applied when you use `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Property)`, which calls through the `TemplateHelpers`.

Comment: Yeah, I also walked through the framework code and noticed the same thing as you did. I was still hopeful though that some one would have shown me something I was missing :(
I'll look into using DisplayForModel, thanks.

Comment: @PaulRivera - Not `DisplayForModel()`, just `DisplayFor()`.

Comment: Right, my original answer referenced `DisplayForModel` but I have updated it as `DisplayFor` will also use the `TemplateHelpers` and respect the `DisplayFormat`.

Comment: I tried it with DisplayFor, and walking thru the framework I can see a difference, however, it still does not work.

Comment: Hmm. It worked in my test view that I had defined as follows. The only difference I could see is that I had Phone on my test model directly, rather than model.Patient.Phone: Whole display
@Html.DisplayForModel()

OnlyThePhone
@Html.DisplayForModel("OnlyThePhone")

DisplayTextFor
@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Phone)

DisplayFor
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Phone)